# The user-specific data is deleted on login to firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created an ios app that uses firebase as backend. I have implemented login and offline use.

The data structure for the database is:

```
"users" : {
    "Ms7KgWe02UZDcmhlA4CojXIrYNS2" : {
      "some_data" : {
        "-KdCKYzulR4CLLnCgZxV" : {
          "something" : "something",
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And when I log in, the "some data" just disappears.

Does anyone know what can cause this?

Comment: Have you made sure your login is still active? If you have the default rules set auth must be valid to read the data.

Comment: For example, in your controllers viewDidLoad method check if FIRAuth.auth().currentuser is nil

Comment: Yes, the login is still active. I can add more data from the app to the firebase database. But, when I log out, and the log in again the data disappears from the database. I can see data just disappearing from the firebase console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had this line

```
currentUserRef?.setValue(self.user?.email)
```

Everything work as intended after removing it

Comment: so it was wiping out all the user data on each run lol yikes! good catch